# No such file or directory error on DD commands

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, dd

I'm trying to run DD commands to fix a cell phone issue in Ubuntu 14.04.  I'm running Ubuntu from a DVD side-by-side with Windows 8 on a 64 bit machine and have automount disabled.

For example when I try to run `dd if=home/name/Desktop/sbl1.img of=/dev/sdb2` I get the error message

```
 "dd: failed to open (location) : No such file or directory"
```

but the file is indeed in that location.  I have tried using both `name@ubuntu:~$` and `root@ubuntu:~#` same result both ways.  `"Name" is an administrator account`. Any ideas on what the issue is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command should be "`dd if=/home/name/Desktop/sbl1.img of=/dev/sdb2`". You didn't type the / before home. Also DD should be run with root privilidges. Personally, like most people I just use sudo in front of the DD command, but the official DD documentation advises against the use of sudo with DD, because under certain circumstances sudo can be interrupted. Therefore it is better to run DD as root. You can do this by typing "`sudo -i`". You are now root, and can then run the DD command "`dd if=/home/name/Desktop/sbl1.img of=/dev/sdb2`".

Sources:

- http://postbin.per.red/pages/article22/page.php